# Using MarkLogic Content Pump to load triples Java

Tags: marklogic, mlcp

Is there any Java example or JavaDoc for MarkLogic Content Pump (MLCP)?

I have MLCP dependencies added by Maven without any problem.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you're looking to invoke mlcp within Java code instead of via the command line - here's one example - https://github.com/rjrudin/ml-camel-mlcp/blob/master/src/main/java/com/marklogic/camel/component/mlcp/MlcpProducer.java#L62 . This is a simple class that makes it easy to call mlcp from a Camel route, and to do, it invokes the ContentPump class directly in Java code.